# Subseting a matrix based in a TRUE/FALSE matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have matrix of true and false value named originaldata. And a second matrix with X measurement called finalmatrix. To conserve in the final matrix only the values that are TRUE in originaldata and set to 0 the rest, I'm doing the following loop

```
 for (row in 1:sqrt(length(finalmatrix)))
 {
     for (col in 1:sqrt(length(finalmatrix))) 
     {
      if (originaldata[row,col] == FALSE) {
        finalmatrix[row,col] <- 0
      }
   }
 }
```

But this is painfully slow, specially with big matrices. Is there a more straightforwad way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could multiply the two matrixes and all values with `FALSE` in `originaldata` would become zero.

`finalmatrix <- finalmatrix * originaldata`

Answer (score 1):

You can just set all the false elements to zero directly.

```
finalmatrix[!originaldata] = 0
```